# Adjust a width based on parent w/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to be able to adjust a width of a class based on a width of a parent. Currently .myClass has a width assigned in CSS. Would something like this work:

```
.myClass {
    color: #000;
    width:100px;
}

$(".myClass").width($(".myClass").parent().width());
```

This will be applied to a `<DIV>` and the parent could be a `<TD>` or another `<DIV>`.

Comment: I know this is just an example, and you might want to do something different in the real code, but why do you need to do this? Any element with display:block will take up 100% of the width of the parent automatically. If you don't need 100%, you should probably either user percentage width on your child element, or add margins/padding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have should work but I would probably change it to this:

```
$(".myClass").css("width",$(".myClass").parent().css("width"));
```

You might be able to use `this` instead of the second `$(".myClass")`, but you'd have to test that.

Keep in mind that it's not changing the class itself.  It's changing the width of any element that uses that class.

UPDATE:

If you are going to be doing any sort of calculations with the parent width then you should probably stick with your original method.  I like `css` when you are applying styles "as is" but that is a personal preference.  If you are doing any kind of modifications to the parent value then `width` is probably better.

From the width documentation:

> The .width() method is recommended
>   when an element's width needs to be
>   used in a mathematical calculation.

Comment: Thanks. one question though. Will it detect parent width if the parent does not have a css class or ID associated with it? Shouldn't it be something like: $(".myClass").css("width",$(".myClass").parent().width());

Comment: You don't have to define a class or even CSS for the parent in order to get it's width using either method.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gGfYn/

Comment: I think your method is more appropriate since we're trying to assign it via CSS and it does need PX. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "independent of parent"?

Comment: If you're on an older version of jquery you may want to be careful with this approach.  If the parent has an inline style setting the width to a percentage, you will not get the intended behavior because this will return the percentage.  http://jsfiddle.net/gGfYn/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
var parentW = $('.myClass').parent().width();
$('.myClass').width(parentW);
```

### [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vruTE/)

```
$('.myClass').width( $('.myClass').parent().width() );
```

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vruTE/1/)

And if you have more classes 'myClass':

```
$('.myClass').each(function() {
    var myClass = $(this);
    var parentW = myClass.parent().width();
    myClass.width(parentW);
});
```

### [DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vruTE/2/)

AND HERE IS ONE HARD CODED: (no javascript);)

### [DEMO4](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vruTE/3/)

**And if you followed this song, here is the 'refrain': *(the smart solution)*:**

```
$('.myClass').css({width: 'auto'});
```

### [DEMO5](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vruTE/5/)