# Affix as separate plugin

Tags: affix, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 which dropped the affix plugin, to be replaced by using position: sticky.

However, chrome does not support that yet. And when moving back to bootstrap 3 whole my layout is screwed. And the recommended scrollpos-styler works horrible in combination with bootstrap.
(https://github.com/acch/scrollpos-styler)

So I wondered, is it possible to get the affix plugin separate so I can still use it with bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can copy the plugin from Bootstrap 3. Do not forget to to declare the required CSS classes:

```
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
}

.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title> Bootstrap 4 project :: Home</title>
    
    <!--Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
}

.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
}
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>

    <header style="height:200px;background-color:green;color:white">header</header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" data-offset-bottom="200" style="background-color:red; height:250px;">
                Affixed sidebar
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9" style="height:150vh;">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <footer style="height:200px;background-color:black;color:white;">footer</footer>
    
        <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/HubSpot/tether/v1.2.0/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script>
     /* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: affix.js v3.3.6
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // AFFIX CLASS DEFINITION
  // ======================

  var Affix = function (element, options) {
    this.options = $.extend({}, Affix.DEFAULTS, options)

    this.$target = $(this.options.target)
      .on('scroll.bs.affix.data-api', $.proxy(this.checkPosition, this))
      .on('click.bs.affix.data-api',  $.proxy(this.checkPositionWithEventLoop, this))

    this.$element     = $(element)
    this.affixed      = null
    this.unpin        = null
    this.pinnedOffset = null

    this.checkPosition()
  }

  Affix.VERSION  = '3.3.6'

  Affix.RESET    = 'affix affix-top affix-bottom'

  Affix.DEFAULTS = {
    offset: 0,
    target: window
  }

  Affix.prototype.getState = function (scrollHeight, height, offsetTop, offsetBottom) {
    var scrollTop    = this.$target.scrollTop()
    var position     = this.$element.offset()
    var targetHeight = this.$target.height()

    if (offsetTop != null && this.affixed == 'top') return scrollTop < offsetTop ? 'top' : false

    if (this.affixed == 'bottom') {
      if (offsetTop != null) return (scrollTop + this.unpin <= position.top) ? false : 'bottom'
      return (scrollTop + targetHeight <= scrollHeight - offsetBottom) ? false : 'bottom'
    }

    var initializing   = this.affixed == null
    var colliderTop    = initializing ? scrollTop : position.top
    var colliderHeight = initializing ? targetHeight : height

    if (offsetTop != null && scrollTop <= offsetTop) return 'top'
    if (offsetBottom != null && (colliderTop + colliderHeight >= scrollHeight - offsetBottom)) return 'bottom'

    return false
  }

  Affix.prototype.getPinnedOffset = function () {
    if (this.pinnedOffset) return this.pinnedOffset
    this.$element.removeClass(Affix.RESET).addClass('affix')
    var scrollTop = this.$target.scrollTop()
    var position  = this.$element.offset()
    return (this.pinnedOffset = position.top - scrollTop)
  }

  Affix.prototype.checkPositionWithEventLoop = function () {
    setTimeout($.proxy(this.checkPosition, this), 1)
  }

  Affix.prototype.checkPosition = function () {
    if (!this.$element.is(':visible')) return

    var height       = this.$element.height()
    var offset       = this.options.offset
    var offsetTop    = offset.top
    var offsetBottom = offset.bottom
    var scrollHeight = Math.max($(document).height(), $(document.body).height())

    if (typeof offset != 'object')         offsetBottom = offsetTop = offset
    if (typeof offsetTop == 'function')    offsetTop    = offset.top(this.$element)
    if (typeof offsetBottom == 'function') offsetBottom = offset.bottom(this.$element)

    var affix = this.getState(scrollHeight, height, offsetTop, offsetBottom)

    if (this.affixed != affix) {
      if (this.unpin != null) this.$element.css('top', '')

      var affixType = 'affix' + (affix ? '-' + affix : '')
      var e         = $.Event(affixType + '.bs.affix')

      this.$element.trigger(e)

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      this.affixed = affix
      this.unpin = affix == 'bottom' ? this.getPinnedOffset() : null

      this.$element
        .removeClass(Affix.RESET)
        .addClass(affixType)
        .trigger(affixType.replace('affix', 'affixed') + '.bs.affix')
    }

    if (affix == 'bottom') {
      this.$element.offset({
        top: scrollHeight - height - offsetBottom
      })
    }
  }


  // AFFIX PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // =======================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.affix')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.affix', (data = new Affix(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.affix

  $.fn.affix             = Plugin
  $.fn.affix.Constructor = Affix


  // AFFIX NO CONFLICT
  // =================

  $.fn.affix.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.affix = old
    return this
  }


  // AFFIX DATA-API
  // ==============

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-spy="affix"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = $(this)
      var data = $spy.data()

      data.offset = data.offset || {}

      if (data.offsetBottom != null) data.offset.bottom = data.offsetBottom
      if (data.offsetTop    != null) data.offset.top    = data.offsetTop

      Plugin.call($spy, data)
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
    
       </script>  
       <script>
        $('[data-spy="affix"]').on('affixed.bs.affix', function () {
            // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551429/adjust-a-width-based-on-parent-w-jquery
            $(".affix").css("width",$(".affix").parent().css("width").replace('px','') - 30);
        })
        </script>
    
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Nice @Bass. Are you going to continue support for this? https://github.com/bassjobsen/affix

Answer (score 0):

It works with jquery but it is not listed at the jquery plugins.
Instead it is included with bootstrap 3.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases