# position:sticky; not working with angular 2 and bootstrap4

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I want similar component like [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html#html-template) of bootstrap2 or 3 in bootstrap4 with Angular2.

As bootstrap 4 says it has removed the affix and created position:sticky; for the same. But when I apply it on card its not working.

**a.css**

```
.my-page-header-stick {
   position: sticky;
}
```

**a.html file**

```
<div class="card my-page-header-stick">
    <h1>Page header: This card will stick below the navbar of the single page application</h2>
</div>
...
<!-- other cards of the page -->
```

I want to write minimalistic code, and achieve the same.
Some affix examples:

I found a similar question [Affix as separate plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911695/affix-as-separate-plugin)
which says solution as copy affix from bootstrap 3 and paste in the bootstrap4 but I dont appreciate the answer.

I'm looking for a solution, where I don't have to write CSS as well as JS code and maintain it in future with the folks.